# Is it really bad practice to assign a variable multiple times, as per a NetBeans warning?

Tags: php, netbeans, standards

I have a function that is basically like this:

```
        //Init variable
    $ready = FALSE;

        //if submit
    filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit") ?  $ready = TRUE : $ready = FALSE ; 

        //return the result
    return $ready;
```

NetBeans is warning me against multiple assignments. In other languages this is pretty normal to do. It is the only NetBeans warning that I get. Is this code okay to use?

Comment: I just have to wait bit longer before i can mark it as answered. How is this question off topic, does it not have something to do with php and netbeans? any way others have answered my question with no trouble. Thanks to every one for their input.

Comment: OK i am using a mix of Mureinik, Alexis Peters and Vanadium with the following.

 return filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit"); 

sorry Richard, Vanadium just beat you to it but thanks to all for their input.

Comment: @Class Stacker no problem any more. and in other languages your answer is not correct. In c if you create a variable inside an if statement it is invalid. also keeping with the c theme of trying to keep one return in a function the return variable would need to be created out side of the if statement. Then also keeping with c theme if you create a variable you initialize it. But i have stated in my comment above the solution. and thanksed every one.It wasn't as difficult as others were making it. More of a curiosity that has now been solved with neater code.

Comment: You're right, I didn't look carefully enough to see the real problem with your code snippet. But apart from that, I think you misunderstood my comment. FYI, the ternary operator introduces no local scope. And also, `if` doesn't introduce a local scope by itself in `C`. Rather, it's the `{}` block. Plus, there are tools which warn you if your initial assignment to a variable gets overwritten unconditionally without the value having been used before, so I'm inviting you to consider whether there could be exceptions to your dogma of _initialise a variable where you declare it_.

Comment: @class stacker, there are obviously exceptions to any rule. This is a matter of opinion that could be argued either way depending on your education and practical experience. But i was taught to try when possible to follow the "c++ 101 coding standards". As it turned out, i could have used the filter_input call to initialize the variable but in the end i didn't need the variable at all. Thanks to some constructive help from other forum members i ended up with a more concise function. Thanks for your input i never turn down an opportunity to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code to a single assignment so you don't even need the ternary operator:

```
$ready = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit");
```

Comment: thanks you for your response makes perfect sense. thanks

Comment: or, do not use assignment at all and use `return filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit");`

Answer (score 2):

Think of the ternary operator `?:` as a function call:

```
$var = decideOnValue($condition, $valueIfConditionTrue, $valueIfConditionFalse);
```

and you'll understand why Netbeans is generating those warnings.

The common usages of the `?:` operator are:

- decide on what value to assign to a variable based on a condition, without resorting to the longer `if/else` construct
- call a function or another, based on a condition, again to shorten the code

Doing more than this is dangerous as it can lead to bugs. For your particular example, if you have a typo and you mistakenly write `$redy = FALSE` then you introduce a subtle bug, even if the code is syntactically correct, and the PHP static analyser that comes with Netbeans tries to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite you code to be a little less, and Netbeans won't paranoid you:

```
$ready = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit") ?  TRUE : FALSE; 
return $ready;
```

Comment: or just -> return filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit") ?  TRUE : FALSE;

Answer (score 0):

Slight misuse of the syntax.  Try:

```
$ready = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit") ? true : false;
```

$ready must be either true or false at this point so there is no need to initialize to false beforehand.